# Deploy Mahout jobs on a cluster

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, mahout

I'm new to Hadoop/Mahout, I understand the concepts, but I'm having issues deploying Mahout jobs to an already set cluster of computers.

I have used Mahout on single computer, but what should I do to make it up and running to an already formed Hadoop cluster?

I have a cluster with Hadoop 0.20.2 installed, and Mahout 0.9, which contains Hadoop 1.2.1. What jars should I copy so I could run code that contains Mahout calls, or what else should I do to make it work on Hadoop cluster?

Any suggestion/example/tutorial would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

important link for your problem

https://mahout.apache.org/users/clustering/k-means-commandline.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sorry for late response. Just to check, so if $HADOOP_HOME and $HADOOP_CONF_DIR are set, then the job is run on cluster, else its run on local machine? And also, if I have 1.2.1 version of Hadoop jar packed with Mahout, and 0.20.2 installed on the cluster, mahout job will run using installed 0.20.2 version of Hadoop? Is there a way to check if the job was ran on the cluster? Thanks again.